# Flurry Native ADs Delegate method not called

Tags: ios, swift, flurry, native-ads

Hello i have implemented flurry native ads in my ios app. But its delegate method is not called so could not display the ads. I have also downloaded the demo code from [here](https://github.com/flurry/native-advertising-sample-swift). its working fine but same implementation is not working in my app. Below is my code. In this code none of the delegate method is called.

```
let nativeAd = FlurryAdNative(space: "Tester")
    //    var nativeAdsWanted = 3
    //    let adFetchRetryMaximum = 10
    //    var adFetchRetryCount = 0

    // this list will hold ads that we have requested but are not ready
    var pendingAdList: [FlurryAdNative] = []
    // this list will hold our ready ads that will be dispalyed
    var nativeAdList: [FlurryAdNative] = [] {
        didSet {
            print(nativeAdList)
        }
    }
        override func viewDidLoad()
         {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                self.initFlurryAds()
         }

func initFlurryAds() {
        var newAdsList : [FlurryAdNative] = []

        //setting the ad delegate a view controller
        nativeAd?.adDelegate  = self
        nativeAd?.viewControllerForPresentation = self

        //fetching the ad from Flurry and then addding it to our list of new ads
        nativeAd?.fetchAd()
        print(nativeAd!)
        newAdsList.append(nativeAd!)
    }

func adNativeDidFetchAd(nativeAd: FlurryAdNative!){
        print("Native Ad for Space \(nativeAd.space) Received Ad with \(nativeAd.assetList.count) assets");
        nativeAdList.append(nativeAd)
    }

    // Informational callback invoked when there is an ad error
    func adNative(nativeAd: FlurryAdNative!, adError: FlurryAdError, errorDescription: NSError!){
        NSLog("Native Ad for Space \(nativeAd.space) Received Error \(adError), with description: \(errorDescription)")
    }

    func adNativeDidDismiss(_ nativeAd: FlurryAdNative!) {

    }

    func adNativeDidLogImpression(_ nativeAd: FlurryAdNative!) {

    }

    func adNativeWillPresent(_ nativeAd: FlurryAdNative!) {

    }

func adNativeExpandToggled(_ nativeAd: FlurryAdNative!) {

}
```

Comment: Can you send a copy of this project to integration@flurry.com? We can dig into this there.

Comment: https://github.com/flurry/native-advertising-sample-swift